# Find number in a certain range satisfying three modulus requirements

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

I have to show that $\;x = 37\quad$ is the only number $\;x\in \{n\in \Bbb N: n \le 110\}\text{ that satisfies: }x\equiv 1 \pmod 2,\;x\equiv 2 \pmod 5\qquad$ and $\;x\equiv 4 \pmod {11}.$

By using The Chinese remainder theorem I've found, that:

$$x=55\cdot 1 + 22\cdot 2 + 10\cdot 4 = 139,$$

but $\;139\equiv 29 \pmod {110}.$

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you need to also compute the solution $\,x=37\,$  or are you given the solution  and only need to show that it's the *unique* solution in said interval?

Comment: The solution is x = 37 and I have to show that it's the only solution that satisfies those three congruences

Comment: Then why are you (re)computing it in tthe question?  If you only need to show said uniqueness then that follows immediately from CRT.  To *verify* that it is a solution just calculate its remainder mod $2,5,11,\,$ you don't need to apply the CRT formula.

Comment: I have to show its uniqueness. So I don't know if calculating its remainder mod 2,5,11 is enough?

Comment: As I said, the uniqueness is immediate from CRT. Please tell is the version of CRT that you are working with. What precisely it its statement?

Comment: As Bill said, the CRT takes care of uniqueness, as long as we know that certain basic conditions are met. If you look at the precise statement of the theorem you're working with, that should help you.

Answer (score 3):

***Appplying CRT correctly***

I'll address the question of uniqueness, but I see a mistake in how you applied the Chinese Remainder Theorem, so I think that's worth addressing, too. There are different ways to use the CRT. The usual constructive approach is to write:

$$1\cdot 55\cdot n_2 + 2\cdot 22\cdot n_5 + 4\cdot 10\cdot n_{11}$$

where $n_2$ is a multiplicative inverse of $55$, modulo $2$, $n_5$ is a multiplicative inverse of $22$, modulo $5$, and $n_{11}$ is a multiplicative inverse of $10$, modulo $11$. In your solution, these multiplicative inverses appear to be missing, which is why you got an incorrect answer. In this case, we could take $n_2=1$, $n_5=3$, and $n_{11}=-1$. That would lead to the solution:

$$1\cdot 55\cdot 1 + 2\cdot 22\cdot 3 + 4\cdot 10\cdot (-1)=55+132-40=147$$

We have $147\equiv 37\pmod{110}$, so that matches the correct answer.

***Uniqueness***

Now, what about uniqueness? According to the CRT, as it's usually stated, if we have relatively prime moduli, and if $M$ is the product of those moduli, then our solution will be unique modulo $M$. To verify this, we need to check that $2$, $5$ and $11$ are pairwise coprime, and we need to check that their product is $110$. Both of these are immediate, so we have uniqueness in the desired modulus.

This guarantee of uniqueness comes from the fact that every possible set of remainders modulo $2$ and $5$ and $7$ occurs for some number from $0$ to $109$. There are $110$ possible sets of remainders, so none of them can show up twice in the stated range. These considerations should come up in the proof of CRT, though, and aren't necessary to make every time you apply it.

***More efficient application of CRT***

As an aside, I don't actually use the CRT that way. A much easier algorithm is this:

We want a number congruent to $4\pmod{11}$, so we start with $4$. If this number is also congruent to $2\pmod5$, great. Else, add $11$ repeatedly until we have a number congruent to $2\pmod{5}$:

$$4+11=15\\
15+11=26\\
26+11=37$$

Now, if this number is already congruent to $1\pmod2$, then we're done. Otherwise, we could start adding $55$ repeatedly until we got the desired $\mod2$ congruence. In this case, we're already there.

Comment: You misunderstood the question. OP doesn't need to compute the solution but only verify its *uniquness* in said range.

Comment: I didn't misunderstand the question. Don't be presumptuous. Part of this answer deals with verifying uniqueness - it follows directly from CRT because 110 is the product of three pairwise coprime moduli - but I also added some useful content about how we use CRT because I saw the OP doing it wrong.

Comment: Given that 95% of what you wrote has little to do with the question, I think it is a reasonable presumption to infer that you misunderstood it (which, admittedly, is easy to do given that it is not so clear).

Comment: Even if I did misunderstand the question, which I did not, it's still a pretty big leap to suppose that what's really needed in the world is you telling me that.

Comment: Are you hoping to improve my answer with this conversation? Are you improving MSE by doing this?

Comment: Yes, what other possible reason could there be for such remarks?. Do you think it is optimal to have the "answer" be buried among remarks which have little to do with the actual question? Further, I don't think that the proposed answer "CRT tells us there is a unique solution" is very helpful. Instead of elaborating on motley tangential stuff, it is that point that deserves emphasis - since that (and only that) is precisely what the question concerns.

Comment: I think you should post your own answer, rather than haranguing me. Then you'll be teaching by example, which is much more effective than teaching by immediately getting off on the wrong foot. :)

Comment: Had you approached this differently, we'd be having a very different conversation.

Comment: Example: "Do you think you can edit your answer to say more about the uniqueness?" That's how you get positive responses. You should know this.

Comment: Hey, @BillDubuque, I edited my answer, so your comments weren't wasted. They were just rude.

Answer (score 0):

$$x=4+11X=2+5Y=1+2Z\Rightarrow11X=-2+5Y=-3+2Z$$
The equation $$2Z-5Y=1$$ admits the solution $(Z,Y)=(18,7)$ then the general solution $$Z=18+5t\\Y=7+2t$$ which comes from $$(2Z-5Y)-(2\cdot18-5\cdot7)=2(Z-18)-5(Y-7)=0$$
For $t=0$ one has $Z=18$ and $Y=7$ which corresponds to $X=\dfrac{-2+5\cdot7}{11}=3$
Thus taking any of the three values, for example $X=3$ we have $$x=4+3\cdot11=37$$

It is easy to verify that since $$4+11X=2+5(7+2t)\iff11X=33+10t$$ in order to have $X$ integer the parameter $t$ should be multiple of $11$ so the next value to be considered is $t=11$ which give $x=147\gt110$. Thus $37$ is the only integer asked.